# MPU9150 - Yaw angle Drift

Tags: quadcopter

I use MPU9150, also use DCM and Complimentary filter to compute roll, pitch and yaw. However, my Yaw is not so smooth. How can I solve that problem?

I looked at the datasheet of MPU9150, but I didn't see anything related to sampling frequency of magnetometer like gyro and accel.

Comment: Do you use magnetometer data alone for the yaw-estimation?
Consider doing some sensor fusion with your gyro and your magnetometer data, this will increase the reliability of the produced data.

Comment: I used sensor fusion. I see some article about magnetometer calibration. Does this affect the reliability?

Comment: Calibration will help with high drift or bad data in general.
But you said your problem is that the yaw value is kind of "jerking". This should not happen if the data from magnetometer and the integration of the gyro are used to get the yaw value. the integration of the gyro should smooth it.

Comment: Actually, if i let the sensor down on the table, but the yaw fluctuates in very wide range, the gap can be 10 degree

Comment: Ok I think it'd better to see the code.
Pls come to the Chatroom (same name as question) to discuss and find a solution. This is a very specific problem and the discussion should not be in the comments.

Comment: I use Tiva C from TI and sensorhub booster pack. The code is the sample comp_dcm from TivaWare 2.0

Comment: Is the magnetometer data drifting, or just the yaw estimation value?

Comment: If the raw data from the magnetometer fluctuates quite widely. How can i fix it. I use the tilt-compensated heading. Is that ok? Some guy talked about combining magnetometer's data along with gyro to get more precise yaw angle. What algorithm we need to use?

Comment: Have you adjusted for magnetic declination